# Ivy debug message level within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy

I want to change ivy message level to debug my ivy-settings in eclipse and I have no idea how I to set it to debug/verbose level.

Comment: Check out the message options available when running Ivy.  http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/standalone.html

Comment: Any particular reason to down rate my question?

Comment: I'm running Ivy from eclipse,I've the link before, and still have no idea where to put that setting

Comment: If it is in eclipse is this what you are looking for then? http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/console.html

Comment: exactly! Cheers and sorry for a bit silly question. I really don't have much time to finish project and didn't want to spend to much time looking for this feature. Cheers!

Comment: @Zoop maybe you should post this as an answer with the screenshot, It may not be a great question but your answer helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future reference:

You can change the Ivy message level on IvyDE by following: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/console.html

Message level can be changed when running Ivy as a standalone program by adding "-verbose" or "-debug" args.  ex: java -jar ivy.jar -verbose

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add that if you are running the Ivy tasks **through Ant in Eclipse**, you can set the verbosity level to -verbose for Ivy as follows:

- Run menu > External Tools > External Tools Configurations
- Choose the build you are running
- Add '-verbose' to the Arguments textarea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/history/latest-milestone/console.html

via Zoop's answer [SO: 11744878/611007](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744878/611007)

basically: **eclipse > window > show views > other >** type: **console**

in the console view that should appear, on the right choose a console:
[image: window-like icon with star-ish 'new' symbol with dropdown containing 'ivy console']

and in the bug-icon dropdown you can select the loglevel too:

[image: bug with dropdown containing different loglevels]